# A proof of Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

My instructor has given me a proof of Banach-Steinhaus theorem which is also known as **Uniform Boundedness Theorem** which I find hard to grasp. Here it is $:$

**Uniform Boundedness Theorem** $:$

> > Let $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ be a Banach space and $(Y,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed linear space. Let $\mathcal A \subset B(X,Y)$ be a pointwise bounded family of bounded linear transformations from $X$ to $Y$. Then the family $\mathcal A$ is uniformly bounded.

**Proof** $:$ Let $T \in \mathcal A$. Then for each $n \geq 1$ the set $\{x \in X : \|Tx\| \leq n \}$ is a closed set in $X$. $\implies$ $X \setminus \{x \in X : \|Tx\| \leq n \}$ is an open set in $X$ i.e. the set $\{x \in X : \|Tx\| > n \}$ is an open set in $X$. So $\underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\bigcup} \{x \in X : \|Tx\| > n \}$ is an open set in $X$ i.e. $\{x \in X : \underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\sup} \|Tx\| > n \}$ is an open set in $X$. Let  $V_n =\{x \in X : \underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\sup} \|Tx\| > n \}$, $n \geq 1$. Then $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = \{x \in X : \underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\sup} \|Tx\| = \infty \}$. If $\exists$ $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $V_{n_0}$ is not dense in $X$ then $E_{n_0} = X - V_{n_0}$ is closed and contains a non-empty open set. So it's interior is non-empty. Hence $\exists$ $x_0 \in E_{n_0}$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the closed ball $\overline B(x_0;\epsilon) \subset E_{n_0} = \{x \in X : \underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\sup} \|Tx\| \leq n_0 \}$. Now take $T \in \mathcal A$ and $y \in \overline B(0 ;1)$ then $x_0 + \epsilon y \in B(x_0;\epsilon)$. So $\epsilon \|Ty \| = \|T(\epsilon y)\| = \|T(x_0+\epsilon y - x_0)\| = \|T(x_0+\epsilon y) - T(x_0)\| \leq \|T(x_0+\epsilon y) \| + \|T(x_0)\| \leq n_0 + n_0 = 2n_0$ $\implies$ $\|T(y)\| \leq \frac {2n_0} {\epsilon}$. Since $y \in \overline B(0 ;1)$ is arbitrary so we have $\|T\| \leq \frac {2n_0} {\epsilon}$. Also $T \in \mathcal A$ was arbitrary and hence $\underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\sup}\|T\| \leq \frac {2n_0} {\epsilon} = M$ (say).

This completes the proof.

I don't understand that what the proof actually is. What does it try to prove? Also as a corollary he (my instructor) stated that if $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a normed linear space then either $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is dense or an empty set.

Why is it so? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think your intersection being empty or dense comes from an appeal to the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Here the family is given to be pointwise bounded hence for all $x \in X$, $\underset {T \in \mathcal A} {\sup} \|Tx\| < \infty$. So in our case $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n = \emptyset$. Right?

Comment: Hence there should exist some $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $V_{n_0}$ is not dense by Baire's category theorem. So we are done with the proof. Right?

Comment: According to Baire's category theorem we know that countable intersection of dense open sets is dense.

Comment: So if each $V_n$ was dense; since they are all open so their intersection $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is also dense by Baire's category theorem which is not true in our case. Which gives rise to some $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $V_{n_0}$ is not dense in $X$. Right or not?

Comment: Could you please clarify in your question what, *exactly*, you don't understand in the proof?

Comment: If the family $\mathcal A$ was not pointwise bounded it is not uniformly bounded. Because uniform boundedness $\implies$ pointwise boundedness. So there does not exist any $V_n$ which is not dense for otherwise the family $\mathcal A$ becomes uniformly bounded. Hence all the $V_n$'s are open and dense. Since $X$ is a Banach space so $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is dense.

Comment: This proves the fact that if $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a normed linear space then $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is either dense or an empty set.

Comment: @Aloizio Macedo I have understood everything myself just now. Look at my comments above.

Comment: What is the problem with $\theta$ instead of $0$ @Aloizio Macedo?

Comment: It may be of use to see where the theorem applies. Rudin's $\textit{Real and Complex Analysis}$, Chapter 5, pg 101 gives an example of an application to the classic problem of convergence of Fourier series.